# Calling vue v-model from inside jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have this jquery code that i run when the mounted hook runs

```
  mounted() {
    this.$progress.finish();
    
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var marker = null;
var map = null;
function initialize() {
      var $latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
      var $longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
      var latitude = -1.286389;
      var longitude = 36.817223;
      var zoom = 16;

      var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: zoom,
        center: LatLng,
        panControl: false,
        zoomControl: true,
        scaleControl: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      if (marker && marker.getMap) marker.setMap(map);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Drag Me!',
        draggable: true
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker) {
        var latLng = marker.latLng;
        $latitude.value = latLng.lat();
        $longitude.value = latLng.lng();
        this.property_coordinates = 'hello world';
      });


    }
    initialize();
    $('#findbutton').click(function (e) {
        var address = $("#Postcode").val();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
                $(latitude).val(marker.getPosition().lat());
                $(longitude).val(marker.getPosition().lng());
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    
    
  },
```

I want to grab the coordinates when the marker is dragged and this should updat ethe v-model variable property_coordinates

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(marker) {
            var latLng = marker.latLng;
            $latitude.value = latLng.lat();
            $longitude.value = latLng.lng();
            this.property_coordinates = 'hello world';
          });
```

This `this.property_coordinates = 'hello world';` does not update the v-model. How can i update the v-model from within jquery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing special required to update the `property_coordinates` property from JQuery or other javascript outside of Vue.

In this case, [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in the event function is not bound to the vue component.

An arrow function will maintain `this` from he outer scope

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', (marker) => {
            var latLng = marker.latLng;
            $latitude.value = latLng.lat();
            $longitude.value = latLng.lng();
            this.property_coordinates = 'hello world';
          });
```

Otherwise you can create a reference to the outer vue `this`

```
const component = this
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (marker) {
  component.property_coordinates = 'hello world';
});
```

Comment: Good catch with the `this` but you are not addressing the `v-model` question

Comment: @RobertoLangarica There's nothing particular needed to replace one of the reactive data properties. I'm not sure what has been missed? Do you have more context from op?

Comment: OP asks: "How can i update the v-model from within jquery code?" and you spotted an error with the "this" property that was preventing the correct modification of `property_coordinates`, but solving that issue is not answering how you can update the v-model, maybe OP wasn't expecting to use v-model at all and just to modify the component's own data, but te questions reads as a problem updating v-model that is not being addressed in the answer. That is all the context to my comment, either the answer is incomplete or the question wasn't accurate about the problem. Did I miss something?

Comment: [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) are pretty common on SO. Feel free to submit edits to anything that can be improved or add an answer that addresses additional v-model specifics.

Comment: OMG that description of XY questions are pretty accurate